# Resolving too many else-if statements in Swift 3

Tags: swift, if-statement, nested-loops

Problem: Given the inputs of the function, test each user to make sure they conform to the following conditions: 
1. Each user in the users array cannot share a chatroom with the current user. (The Chatroom object has two properties 'firstUserId', and 'secondUserId'.
2. Each user in the users array is not the current user. 
3. Each user in the users array  is within 5 mile radius of current user.

At the call sight of the completion handler, I check if a User object has a value of true, if so, I show it to the current user as a potential match.

Now, I quickly brute forced this solution, but cringe every time I look at it. It just seems very inefficient. Any tips on a more elegant solution is much appreciated!

```
typealias validUsersCompletionHandler = (_ users: [User: Bool]) -> Void

private func validateNewUsers(currentUser: User, users: [User], chatrooms: [Chatroom], completionHandler: validUsersCompletionHandler?) {

    var results: [User: Bool] = [:]

    let currentUserCoords = CLLocation(latitude: currentUser.latitude, longitude: currentUser.longitude)

    for user in users {
        let newUserCoords = CLLocation(latitude: user.latitude, longitude: user.longitude)
        let distance = currentUserCoords.distance(from: newUserCoords)
        // // 1 mile = 1609 meters, 8046.72 = 5 miles.
        for chatroom in chatrooms {
            if currentUser.id == chatroom.firstUserId && user.id == chatroom.secondUserId {
                results[user] = false
            } else if currentUser.id == chatroom.secondUserId && user.id == chatroom.firstUserId {
                results[user] =  false
            } else if user.id == currentUser.id {
                results[user] = false
            } else if distance > 8046.72 {
                results[user] = false
            } else {
                results[user] = true
            }
        }
    }
    completionHandler?(results)
}
```

// ************************************************************************

// Below is my revised version of the method. Slightly more elegant I suppose?

// ************************************************************************

```
typealias validUsersCompletionHandler = (_ users: [User: Bool]) -> Void

private func validateNewUsers(currentUser: User, users: [User], chatrooms: [Chatroom], completionHandler: validUsersCompletionHandler?) {

    var results: [User: Bool] = [:]

    var isInRange = false

    var distance: Double = 0 {
        didSet {
            if distance > 8046.72 {
                isInRange = false
            } else {
                isInRange = true
            }
        }
    }

    let currentUserCoords = CLLocation(latitude: currentUser.latitude, longitude: currentUser.longitude)

    let currentUserId = currentUser.id

    for user in users {

        let userId = user.id

        let newUserCoords = CLLocation(latitude: user.latitude, longitude: user.longitude)

        distance = currentUserCoords.distance(from: newUserCoords)
        // // 1 mile = 1609 meters, 8046.72 = 5 miles.

        for chatroom in chatrooms {

            switch (currentUserId, userId, isInRange) {

            case (chatroom.firstUserId,chatroom.secondUserId, _), (_, _, false),(chatroom.secondUserId, chatroom.firstUserId, _), (_, currentUserId, _): results[user] = false

            default: results[user] = true

            }
        }

    }

    completionHandler?(results)

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the if statement with switch... Or you can make tuple with 
(currentUserId, userId)

```
 //always check for optionals
    guard let currentUserId = currentUser.id, let userId = user.id, else{
    return
    }
   //The switch should have this format:
    switch (currentUserId, userId){
    //currentUserId == chatroom.firstUserId,  userId = chatroom.secondUserId)
    case (chatroom.firstUserId,chatroom.secondUserId):
    //do your things
    break
    case (chatroom.secondUserId,firstUserId):
    //do other things
    break
    default:
    break
    }
```

You can  even use the case with declaration or comparing more options:

```
    switch value{
    case let x where value > 10:
    //When value is bigger than 10..etc
    default:
    break
    }
```

For better use, see: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html

Wish happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you. Your approach makes sense. What bothers me most is having to put all this logic inside the inner-for loop, meaning it will be executed over every chatroom object, for every user object. I'll just have to think of something more efficient, but I think you sufficiently answered my questions so I'm checking it off as correct.

Comment: I would have to see your whole code, which you are intending to do to help you, but I think you can implement some function on class User, which handles setting up everything... But as I say, I¨d need to see your code... Anyway thanks for marking my answer! :)

Comment: This method is in a singleton class called UserProvider, which does most of my work for fetching users from database and what not. What I have shown is a private helper method. I'm still struggling with understanding how i should structure my objects in terms of architecture, and in the back of my head have been wondering if all this should be in an extension of the User class.

Comment: The `break` statements are not needed here: once the scope of the "body" of a `case` statement is reached, the `switch` will break (default behaviour).

Comment: Do you mind checking the revised version of the method? I've tested it and it works properly. But is it a solid looking method, to solve this specific problem? I ask, Because I'll probably post the complete project to GitHub for potential employers to view.

Comment: @dfri yes, but according to apple official documentation, you should use the break statement, although I don't use them too...

Comment: @AnonProgrammer according to this, in almost every case you set the value to false and in default to true... I would do the oposite or rejoin all cases into one like:

`case (chatroom.firstUserId,chatroom.secondUserId, _), (_, _, false),(chatroom.secondUserId, chatroom.firstUserId, _), (_, currentUserId, _): 
results[user] = false
default:
results[user] = true`

Comment: @DominikBucher Excellent! I will take your advice. Thanks for helping me clean this method up a bit.

Comment: @DominikBucher Apple/Swift Lang. Guide does _not_ recommend using `break` at the end of non-empty `case` bodies. You might be mixing this up with the special case of empty `case` bodies (e.g. used to ignore/discard action for a specific pattern in a `switch` statement), which wont compile without e.g. an explicit `break` statement (as mentioned in the Language Guide), or a single empty tuple `()` expression. Generally, looking at the source of of Swift's own stdlib, implicitness is preferred over explicitness, given that the former is allowed due to an intended language feature.

Comment: seems you are misunderstanding my whole answer and how in which context I answer @dfri

Comment: @DominikBucher not at all, I'm simply following up on my first comment, which very straight-forwardly stated that explicit `break` statements at the end of non-empty `case` bodies is superfluous, and not in accordance with the examples of the Language Guide. In the context of `switch` statements, `break` need generally only be used for 1) early exits (pre-maturely abrupting program flow in a `case` body) or 2) in `case` bodies that are otherwise empty (e.g. the `default` case in your example above). You answered my first comment saying that explicit breaks _should_ be used, which is not true.

Comment: ... For a language such as C++, where fallthrough is the default behavior, natually the `case`-ending `break`:s are necessary (if fallthrough is not wanted), but this is not the case for Swift, where `break` is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can store your tuple values somewhere in struc (should change the logic a bit) but you can do:

```
struct myBeautifulCases{
static let userIsCurrent = (_,currentUserId,_)
static let sameChatroom = (chatroom.secondUserId, chatroom.firstUserId, _)
static let sameChatroomAlt = (chatroom.secondUserId, chatroom.firstUserId, _)
static let isWithinRange = case (_, _, false)

}
```

Now you can cover the ugly tuples with variable names, but you should change the logic a bit :) Wish you best luck and successful project :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Last question. I should change logic to achieve what? To avoid nested for loops, or to have this method self contained in user object? With the given inputs of the function, This is the general way I thought about solving. I know more time spent on HackerRank is probably needed haha!